# In jquery, what's the difference between '.add()' and ',' (comma)?

Tags: jquery

I know that many things can be done in different ways, none of which necessarily and always better than others; So, having multiple ways to do the same is generally good: but, the jQuery '.add()' method and the jQuery comma selector are just two ways to do the same thing or differ from one another (in this particular use as selector)?

```
 $("p").add("span").css("background", "yellow");
 $("p, span").css("background", "yellow");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rudijuri/gg3vfmcp/3/

(sorry for the external link to jsfiddle, but the snippet doesn't work using touch device, like mine now)

Comment: I think both of them are the same. But I will go for `.add()` for readability, especially when I need to put each of it in new lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially they're the same. As the jQuery documentation on [multiple selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) (`(“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)`) says (emphasis mine):

> You can specify any number of selectors to combine into a single
>   result. This multiple expression combinator is an efficient way to
>   select disparate elements. The order of the DOM elements in the
>   returned jQuery object may not be identical, as they will be in
>   document order. **An alternative to this combinator is the .add()
>   method**.

Answer (score 1):

In this case use it as a parallel selector or both p and span objects, if you want to select the spans that are in the p objects you have to insert:

```
$("p > span").css("background", "yellow");
```

or

```
$("p").find("span").css("background", "yellow");
```

Comment: Your answer revolves around descendant or child elements, which the OP asked nothing about